# Bit Coin Hashing Algorithm

Tags: c#, sha256

I, like many hopeless romantics in the online world, believe that I can successfully mine bit coins. Problems is, I can't get the basic algorithm correct for taking data from a previous mine block and creating the hash for the next mined block. I understand from several articles that we start with the current hash of a block, reverse and append the merkel root, add the nonce, then get the SHA256 hash of that string.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //get the hash of the current block
        string currentHash = 
        @"000000000000000000c5c04011f9a3fb5f46064fed7e06dcdae69024ed6484c1";

        //get the merkel root
        string merkel = 
        @"f73a382814c51cbc5a59ab9817ac54c63decb7b3dac5b049df5213c029162bdf";

        //reverese the merkel root
        char[] c = merkel.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(c);
        merkel = new string(c);

        //get a hash object that returns SHA256
        Hash hash = new Hash();

        //get the nonce that mined the block
        uint nonce = 3546041956;

        //string together current hash, merkel root and the hex of the nonce
        string stringTotal = currentHash + merkel + nonce.ToString("x2");

        //calculate the SHA256 hash of the 
        string nextHash = hash.GetHash(stringTotal);

        Console.WriteLine(nextHash);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Anyone know the correct algorithm? I used this block https://blockchain.info/block-height/477065 and tried to calculate the hash for the next block.

Comment: Hashing is only done on a bunch of bytes. Any string you will see when talking about hashing is just representation of the bytes.

Comment: The Hash object takes in the string, converts to bytes, applies the SHA256 algo, then appends each byte in byte[] to a StringBuilder object with ("x2").

Comment: public string GetHash(string input)
        {
            string hash = "";

            byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

            HashAlgorithm ha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] b2 = ha.ComputeHash(b);


            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
           
            foreach(byte i in b2)
            {
                builder.Append(i.ToString("x2"));
            }

            hash = builder.ToString();

            return hash;
        }

Comment: *reverse the merkel root* - I cannot believe you have to reverse the chars of the byte representation (2 chars represents 1 byte)

Comment: Did I not reverse the merkel root correctly in the above code?

Comment: The correct reversed merkel root should start with df2b16... but you get fdb261...

Comment: Sir Rufo, can you please show my how the method the above program uses to reverse the string of bytes is incorrect?

Comment: OK, I have reversed the char, but not the bytes within the char, I see that now. I need pizza.

Comment: Decode the hex string representation to a byte array and just reverse that byte array. Stay away from string when hashing, just use streams or byte arrays.

Comment: @dachizzle37 - Don't forget to use the `@` notation when replying to someone.

Comment: @dachizzle37 - You know that mining BitCoins is a science that has been perfected on dedicated hardware using assembly language? Using C# on a PC can't compete. There are 18 `0`s on your hash - so that's a one in `16^18` (or `4.72236648286965E+21`)  chance of randomly producing the right hash on any trial. On average, the resources you spend on electricity will vastly outweigh your return on BitCoins.

Comment: I'll have to compete by playing a better game.

Comment: By-the-way, Mr. E, "Can't never could."

Answer (score 0):

So I was curious about the same thing. This is what I came up with. It's obviously not production quality, but it gets the idea across and seems to work.

It probably would have been much easier if it weren't for the reverse and swap logic that was practically undocumented everything I was looking.

Anyways, hope this helps. I found a bunch of help here if you're interested: http://trogers.net/2018/01/29/how-to-validate-a-bitcoin-blocks-proof-of-work-c/

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // https://blockchain.info/block-height/286819
        int version = 2;
        string previousBlock = "000000000000000117c80378b8da0e33559b5997f2ad55e2f7d18ec1975b9717";
        string merkelRoot = "871714dcbae6c8193a2bb9b2a69fe1c0440399f38d94b3a0f1b447275a29978a";
        uint nonce = 856192328;
        long timestamp = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse("2014-02-20 04:57:25"), DateTimeKind.Utc)).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        uint bits = 419520339;

        var header = new StringBuilder()
            .Append(ReverseAndSwap(version.ToString("D8")))
            .Append(ReverseAndSwap(previousBlock))
            .Append(ReverseAndSwap(merkelRoot))
            .Append(ReverseAndSwap(timestamp.ToString("x2")))
            .Append(ReverseAndSwap(bits.ToString("x2")))
            .Append(ReverseAndSwap(nonce.ToString("x2")))
            .ToString();

        Debug.Assert(string.CompareOrdinal(header, "0200000017975b97c18ed1f7e255adf297599b55330edab87803c81701000000000000008a97295a2747b4f1a0b3948df3990344c0e19fa6b2b92b3a19c8e6badc141787358b0553535f011948750833") == 0);

        var bytes = HexToBytes(header);

        SHA256 sha = new SHA256Managed();

        bytes = sha.ComputeHash(sha.ComputeHash(bytes)).Reverse().ToArray();

        var hash = BytesToHex(bytes);

        Debug.Assert(string.CompareOrdinal(hash, "0000000000000000e067a478024addfecdc93628978aa52d91fabd4292982a50") == 0);
    }

    private static string ReverseAndSwap(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sb.Append(input[i - (i % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1)]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static byte[] HexToBytes(string hex)
    {
        byte[] hexAsBytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];

        for (int index = 0; index < hexAsBytes.Length; index++)
        {
            string byteValue = hex.Substring(index * 2, 2);
            hexAsBytes[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return hexAsBytes;
    }

    public static string BytesToHex(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            output.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", bytes[i]);
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```